# How to abbreviate a textview at a comma?

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to abbreviate a textview at a comma. IE, if I have a string "Thomas, Brian", I'd like to be able to extract "Thomas"

Here is what I have been trying:

```
String output;
    for (int index = 0; index < string1.length();
    index++) {
         aChar = string1.charAt(index);
         output.append(aChar);
         if(aChar == ',') break;
    }
```

But I get this error: "cannot resolve method at charAt(int)"

Thanks!

Comment: No idea why that's causing a problem (is string1 actually a String?), but using string1.split(",") will make your life easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use just split method in the string to do this.

use the below method to achieve this,

```
private static String getAbbreviateText(String value) {
    String[] splitValue = value.split(",");

    if (splitValue == null || splitValue.length == 0) {
        return "";
    }

    return splitValue[0];
}
```

you can call this method like this,

```
String value = "Thomas, Brian";

String finalValue = getAbbreviateText(value); // this will give Thomas.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function

```
String getAbb(String name){
    String target="";
    if (name.startsWith("\"")){
        int commaIndex=name.indexOf(",");
        target=name.substring(1,commaIndex);
    }
    return target;
}
```

Hope this is what you want